# Usar clase externa para pedir permisos en android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

Estoy implementando una clase externa en mi proyecto de android para manejar los permisos:

```
class RequesterPermissions extends ActivityCompat {

    private final static String TAG = "RequesterPermissions";
    private Activity activity;

    RequesterPermissions(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    boolean checkIfPermissionIsGranted(String permission){
        boolean Return = false;
        int permissionChecked = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.activity, permission);
        if(permissionChecked == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // Permission already granted
            Return = true;
        }else if(permissionChecked == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            // Permission denied
            Return = false;
        }
        return Return;
    }

    void requestForPermission(String[] permission){
        // Open dialog to grant or denied permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.activity, permission, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted
                    Log.d(TAG, permissions[0] + " granted");
                } else {
                    // Permission denied
                    Log.e(TAG, permissions[0] + " denied");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que me tira este error en el método `onRequestPermissionsResult()`:

> Error:(41, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucioné mi problema cambiando el inicio de mi clase de la siguiente forma:

```
class RequesterPermissions extends ActivityCompat {
```

Por:

```
class RequesterPermissions implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya veo que solucionaste tu problema, sin embargo por el error que muestras entiendo que falta agregar la invocacion a *super* dentro del método *onRequestPermissionsResult* de la siguiente forma:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

    ...
}
```

Con tu solución el problema ya no existe porque ya no heredas de una clase (no hay un 'super') sino que implementas una interfaz lo cual podría no ser lo ideal dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer.

Comment: Intenté probar tu solución pero me tira el error `Cannot resolve method 'onRequestPermissionsResult(int, java.lang.string[], int[])' `

Comment: Para usar mi solución la clase tiene que heredar _AppCompatActivity_; No implementar _ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback_. Osea tiene que quedar como `class RequesterPermissions extends AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Estoy implementando parte de tu código pero a mi no me entra a

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

como le haces para que me capture la respuesta

Comment: Esta es el área de respuestas de la pregunta, puedes realizar tu propia pregunta basada en [ask], por lo pronto te sugiero eliminar esta publicación.